# How to Truncate the Decimal Places without Rounding Up?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume i have the following decimal value:

4.584406

I need a simple quick way to truncate the decimal without rounding up, so the output would be 4.5

I'm using T-SQL (SQL Server 2005/2008).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using the [`round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) function you can try this

```
select round(4.584406, 1, 1)
```

the output will be

```
4.5
```

the key is the third parameter

```
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
```

> function
>
> ```
> Is the type of operation to perform. function must be tinyint,
> ```
>
> smallint, or int. When function is
>   omitted or has a value of 0 (default),
>   numeric_expression is rounded. **When a
>   value other than 0 is specified,
>   numeric_expression is truncated.**